# Cant configure timed out user confirmation url page in LoopbackJS

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I try to configure, new registerede user's timed ot confirmation url.
When user clicks on timed out link from mail, screen looks like :

```
{"error":{"name":"Error","status":404,"message":"User not found: 19","statusCode":404,"code":"USER_NOT_FOUND","stack":"Error: User not found: 19\n    at c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback\\common\\models\\user.js:477:19\n    at c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:1524:62\n    at c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:1456:9\n    at Object.async.each (c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:153:20)\n    at allCb (c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:1394:13)\n    at c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-connector-mysql\\node_modules\\loopback-connector\\lib\\sql.js:1071:7\n    at c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\observer.js:166:22\n    at doNotify (c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\observer.js:93:49)\n    at MySQL.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\observer.js:116:5)\n    at MySQL.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (c:\\NodeJS\\UyguncaAdmin\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\observer.js:91:8)"}}
```

I want to send more user-friendly page includes message like "Confirmation mail timed out ...".
I try to use "afterRemote" method, but it does not work. I cant get "in confirm afterRemote" message.

```
MyUser.afterRemote('confirm', function(ctx, inst, next) {
  console.log('in confirm afterRemote...');
  next(); });
```

Is there any way to do this? What is wrong with this afterRemote method?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **server/config.json**
and set  **"disableStackTrace": true** and  **"disableStatusCode": true** 
under **errorHandler** section look below example

Don't forget to vote ;-)

Cheers

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 4000,
  "remoting": {
    "context": {
      "enableHttpContext": false
    },
    "rest": {
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": {
      "origin": true,
      "credentials": true
    },
    "errorHandler": {
      "disableStackTrace": true,
      "disableStatusCode": true
    }
  }
}
```